# Python Library for Finding Duplicate Sub-strings Between Textual Files in Python

Tags: python, string, nlp, substring

I'm trying to identify duplicate blocks of text contained at arbitrary locations within several larger bodies of text, without knowing anything about the texts beforehand. That's to say, given n-many bodies of text, ignore the portions which are duplicate between texts.

**An example:**

5 webpages, each containing an article, but also a navigation menu, footer, sidebar etc.

The article would be unique to each page, but the content in the sidebar, footer, and navigation menus would be the same.

My goal would be to identify the non-article content as being duplicate..

**Some Notes:**

I do not know the contents of the duplicate content beforehand.

The duplicate content could be anywhere within the larger bodies of text between files. It could proceed, precede, or be mixed within.

The duplicate content should be identified from start to finish. i.e. if an entire paragraph is duplicated between files, a substring of that paragraph shouldn't be flagged as duplicate.

I'm digging through the [BioPython](https://biopython.org/) library and its sequence-matching features seem to be on track. I would love to find one more geared towards natural language.

Comment: you can use Counter for solving your problem. ``from collections import Counter``

Comment: Based on only the information here, it sounds like you just extract the first 100 words and the last 100 words and there's your duplicate content -- no library needed.  So I believe the actual problem is more complex.  :)  Could you clarify the question with more explicit information on the input you have and the output you wish to get?

Comment: @JDM Check out the "notes" section. Part of the requirement is that the duplicate content could be located anywhere. As an example, consider a webpage with 100 pages each which contains some similar elements (article text) vs. some duplicate elements (menu items, author boxes, etc.). I'd only be interested in the elements unique to that page.

Comment: @IVI I don't think that'll do it. The issue being that unique words between duplicate sentences shouldn't be flagged as duplicate. That's to say: "the quick brown fox" shouldn't return `the`, `the quick`, `the quick brown`, and `the quick brown fox` as duplicate contents—just the lattermost.

Comment: @theeastcoastwest, that's the trouble, the 'main' part of your question describes text files each containing exactly 1000 words, divided into exactly 3 sections of 100, 800, and 100 words.  But then you generalize it to "larger bodies of text," "sentences," "paragraphs" and so on.  So really it's not at all clear what problem you're trying to solve or what result the solution would give you.  A more realistic, concrete example would make it easier to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: @JDM see the updated question.